# CMake: how to create own list of properties?

Tags: cmake

I have some options in `.cmake` file:

```
option (OPTION_1 "option 1" ON)
option (OPTION_2 "option 2" OFF)
```

Then I want to print out these options like that:

```
foreach (_variableName ${_variableNames})
    message(STATUS "${_variableName}=${${_variableName}}")
endforeach()
```

I expect following output:

```
OPTION_1=ON
OPTION_2=OFF
```

Is it possible to create custom properties list `optionsList` which will contains only my options `OPTION_1` and `OPTION_2` and then get it like that:

```
get_cmake_property (_variableNames optionsList)
```

?

CMake version : 3.7.0-rc1

Best Regards,
Igor

Comment: Did you try `set(optionsList OPTION_1 OPTION_2)`, then `foreach(option ${optionsList}) ...`?